# jqgrid is displaying different datetime based on time zones

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid 4.1.2 version and the server returns date serialized into JSON as below `"\/Date(1314443359000-0700)\/"`.

The problem is jqgrid is not displaying the server datetime but it displays datetime based on local time zone also when I change my local time zone the displayed datetime differs. How I can display the server datetime in jqgrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you described is the *correct* behavior. It is **the same time moment** as in the server. If we both want talk on phone *at the same time* we have to place *the local* time in our outlook calender to be ready at the same moment to speak.

If you need another implementation of the date conversion you can use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter).

**UPDATED**: You can define you `myEditSerialize` function and use if as [serializeEditData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events) or as [serializeRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#saverow). Th can be defined as the following

```
var myEditSerialize = function (data) {
    var obj = $.extend({}, data);
    obj.RolloutTermin = jQuery.datepicker.parseDate('dd.mm.yy', data.RolloutDate);
    if (Date.isInstanceOfType(obj.RolloutDate)) {
        obj.RolloutDate= '\/Date(' + obj.RolloutDate.getTime() + ')\/';
    }
    return JSON.stringify(obj);
}
```

In the example I make date serialization from the column 'RolloutDate' so that it will be converted to the `DateTime` on the server side. If you would use `Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(data)` directly all will works also. I prefer better to use `JSON.stringify` function from [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Comment: I don't think it is the correct behavior. In database the stored datetime is 08/24/2011 04:09:59 AM(US) while the grid is displaying it as 08/25/2011 05:09:59 AM(ASIA) when I change some other data in the edit form and post it this date value overrides the correct date in the database. So the next time I see another date is getting displayed. I'm just looking for a way to display the server datetime in the grid.

Comment: @Mark: I think I understand now your problem. How you change the date **and the time** together? Which control you use to display and to change the datetime? Standard jQuery UI datepicker support only the date changing. I can suggest that you two alternative ways to solve the problem: 1) you use `serializeEditData` to convert the modified date to the server time format or use `jQuery.datepicker.parseDate` and Microsoft `Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize` to serialize the modified data. 2) to place in JSON response the date in ISO 8601 format instead of MS date format.

Comment: @Mark: I updated my answer to clear what I mean under the 1) way described shortly in the my previous comment.

Comment: Is jqgrid displays the datetime in GMT timezone?

Comment: @Mark: If you represent time as the string it will be displayed as it be, but if you represent the time as **`Date` object** the datetime will be hold internally in more complex form. If you have datetime  as an object it means that you have an interest for *the time moment* and not for some textual representation. The time moment should be displayed as the *local* time. In which other form the time could be displayed? If somebody say me 12:20 I understand it always the local time. The same time I see on my computer or on all watches which I have.

Comment: I tried by storing the datetime in UTC(GMT) in database and for showing jqgrid I'm serilaizing it into JSON format (as in the post), the grid not displays the local time but the GMT time. Is this the correct behavior?

Comment: @Mark: I don't understand what you mean. It is not important how you save the datetime **in the database**. Important is only in which format you place the data in the JSON response from the server. So in which format you send the data/time?

Comment: I don't have idea about the format, I'm using the NewtonSoft.JSON library to serialize objects into JSON in my ASP.NET MVC app, the built-in .NET dates are serialized as "\/Date(1314443359000-0700)\/".

Comment: @Mark: you can serialize an anonymous object: `JsonConvert.Serialize(new {total = totalPages, page = currentPage, records = totalRecords, rows = (from item in myitems select new { id = item.id, cell = new [] {myname = item.Name, mydate = item.StartTime.ToString("s")})});` You can use any `DateTime` [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) like "o", "s" or even `item.StartTime.ToString("d", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE").DateTimeFormat)` for example.

Answer (score 1):

I stuck with the same issue as yours. JQGrid is just trying to be smart here. And java script serializer which is default from Microsoft is a real culprit. You just need to send date in standard format thats it. And that will work like anything. Further details are nicely explained over [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx)

As, a simplest solution just use Json.net and things will be solved without messing up the code or doing changes in datetime over client side.

Hope, answer helps you, please let me know if any further details are needed.

Answer (score 0):

this work:

```
colModel:[
...,sorttype:"date",formatter: function (cellval, opts) {
                    var date = new Date(cellval);
                    opts = $.extend({}, $.jgrid.formatter.date, opts);
                    return $.fmatter.util.DateFormat("", date, 'd-M-Y h:i:s', opts);
                },...
]
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $.fmatter.util.DateFormat is not a function

Comment: wanted to say thanks for this, it actually saved me from a problem I was working on - thanks!